# Python/Pandas: dividing dataframe columns if non-empty or greater than zero

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code to divide a series of column by a specific column and then multiply the result times 100, i.e. calculate the % total for each row.

However I get two errors when I try the code below. I suspect due to cases where for a given row/obs 'Type X' or 'Total types' is either zero, empty or maybe contains a non-numeric character?

```
# Calculate Types as % of Total types

df['Type A %'] = 100* (df['Type A #'] / df['Total types'])
df['Type B %'] = 100* (df['Type B #'] / df['Total types'])
df['Type C %'] = 100* (df['Type C'] / df['Total types'])
df['Type D %'] = 100* (df['Type D'] / df['Total types'])

#Sum the columns as a check (should sum to 100%)
#Fetch col names using 'list(df.columns)'

col_list = ['Type A %', 'Type B %', 'Type C %', 'Type D %']
df['Total types %'] = df[col_list].sum(axis=1)
```

The errors:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, not an optimal solution, but I would do the following. Define the function that would compute the percentage and that handles the case of data ambiguity:

```
def percentage(row):
    type_count = row[0]
    total_types = row[1]
    if total_types is None or total_types == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 100 * (int(type_count) / int(total_types))
```

And, finally,

```
df['Type A %'] = df[['Type A #', 'Total_types']].apply(procentage, axis=1)
```

For computing total types %, I would suggest doing data processing -- '2' and 2 are treated as different values by Python.

Comment: Thanks unfortunately this didn't fix my error. It turns out it relates to some cell in the Excel I am reading. The cell appears empty but it really isn't. If I open the file and delete the cell myself then the above error disappears. Odd.

Comment: I would still go with the function above. Just try converting each entry to an integer and compute percentage. If the conversion fails, return 0.

Comment: Thanks. I tried but it won't let me convert it to integer.

Answer (score 0):

you can add an epsilon value to dividers such as 0.00001 or 0.000000001 like this.

Comment: Sure. Can you explain further?